# What type of psychological abuse must a mandated reporter in NY state report as domestic abuse?

Tags: new-york-state, child-abuse, abuse

If a worker of a medical or psychiatric facility suspects psychological abuse rising to the level of constituting domestic violence or has reasonable cause to suspect such by a parent of their adult child who is being brought to them for treatment are they required under laws effective in NY state to report it anywhere? If so what are their responsibilities and what are they required to do, and furthermore, what protective are in place for them in case they face any retaliation for undertaking such statutory reporting obligations.

Comment: I have found NYS bill 7651 which makes an insertion of section 413 subsection 459-i to the social services law in 2018 but this was in 2018. I'm more interested in anything that was in effect in the later months of 2011. Also, I'm wondering if psychological abuses would qualify to invoke these provisions.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but very closely related. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/76601/why-arent-we-allowed-to-intervene-if-a-child-is-being-psychologically-abused

Comment: Yes, and pretty useful!